# How to configure Jenkins job to build with Docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, digital-ocean

I'm attempting to build a branch using Jenkins and a 'docker in the docker' container to build a container from src.

I define the Docker cloud instance here:

[image]

Should an extra tab be available that enable the job to use the Docker cloud instance setup above?

The job is a multi-branch pipeline:

[image]

But when I attempt to configure a job that uses the docker cloud instance, configured above, the option to build with docker is not available:

[image]

The build log contains:

> time="2021-04-04T14:27:16Z" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC:
> cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on
> this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or
> directory" error during connect: Post
> http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=vgpahcarinxfh05klhxyk02gg&shmsize=0&t=ron%2Fml-services&target=&ulimits=null&version=1:
> context canceled [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] }
> [Pipeline] // node [Pipeline] End of Pipeline [Bitbucket] Notifying
> commit build result [Bitbucket] Build result notified ERROR: script
> returned exit code 1 Finished: FAILURE

which suggests the build is searching for Docker on the same host as Jenkins, but I'm attempting to build with Docker on a different host?

Have I configured Docker with Jenkins correctly?

My `Jenkinsfile` contains:

```
node {
      def app
      stage('Clone repository') {
            checkout scm
      }
      stage('Build image') {
            app = docker.build("ron/services")
       }
       stage('Push image') {
      docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'git') {
       app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
       app.push("latest")
              }
           }
        }
```

Update:

Clicking the checkmark at `Expose DOCKER_HOST` , rebuilding contains error:

```
+ docker build -t ron/services .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker cli tries to connect using the docker socket in `/var/run`. This means that no external daemon is configured, for example using the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST`.
Try clicking the checkmark at `Expose DOCKER_HOST`.

Comment: thanks, I've tried clicking the checkmark at export DOCKER_HOST, but similar error, I've updated question.

Comment: It seems you are not spawning build agents using docker, but you simply want to use the docker daemon for building. You can just set the environment variable manually in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear if this is what you are trying to do, but configuring Docker cloud will tell your Jenkins to launch a container on 10.241.0.198 (client), and run your jenkins job in that container. To make this work, there are a couple of things to check:

1. ensure that jenkins user on jenkins server can access port 2371 on client, ie 'Test Connection' returns success
2. Turn on '*Expose DOCKER_HOST*' if  you want to use docker in the container
3. configure ssh so that jenkins user on jenkins server can ssh to the container when it's running on the client (*CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]* in Dockerfile)
4. In Docker Agent Template: configure a label; turn on 'enabled'; configure a docker image to run in the container; set Remote filesystem Root: /home/jenkins
5. In Container Settings: (very important!!) add */var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock* to Volumes

To get your Pipeline job to run on the docker image, set the agent label to the label you provided in step 4.

A couple of gotchas when creating the image to run in the container:

1. install both openssh-clients and openssh-server
2. install java
3. install any other build tools you might need, eg git
4. install docker if you want docker in docker support
5. configure for sftp in /etc/ssh/sshd_config eg, Add

- 

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Match group sftp
X11Forwarding no
AllowTCPForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```